# Memory layout of vector<foo> that contains some foo_subclass elements

Tags: c++, vector

I'm doing postmature optimization on some algorithms that heavily use `std::vector<foo>`.  One of my optimizations involved subclassing foo for certain cases, meaning that a `vector<foo>` will contain both `foo`'s and `foo_subclass`'s.

`foo` has only a `char*` and an `int`, while `foo_subclass` adds a `std::string`.  It's my understanding that each of these, individually, would occupy a fixed-width slot within the vector (with a pointer for `foo_subclass`'s string), but how are they allocated in a container when they're mixed?

Comment: It is very simple: your container holds only `foo`s. It knows nothing about sub-classes.

Comment: Well I know I can add a foo_subclass object to the vector; are you saying that the "extension" is allocated elsewhere and pointed to?

Comment: @Chap no, you cannot add a `foo_subclass` object to the `vector`.  You can slice the `foo` component of a `foo_subclass` off and make a copy of that and put it in the `vector`.

Comment: No, there is no extension. The vector only contains `foo`s. See [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Comment: @Chap: no. That extension will be [sliced off](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Comment: @Chap: If you want to have objects of an abstract type in the vector then you must store pointers /smart pointers for the objects in the vector (1 indirection). The vector elements must have the same type. For an instance pointers of the same type (e.g., pointing to objects of the same abstract base class).

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is "you cannot do this".  A `std::vector<foo>` cannot contain `foo_subclass`: if you try to put a `foo_subclass` into the `vector`, it slices the `foo` component of the `foo_subclass`, makes a copy of that, and puts that `foo` into the `vector`.

The longer answer is that there are two ways you can approach this.

First, you can create a `std::vector< std::unique_ptr<foo> >` -- a `vector` of owning smart pointers to `foo`.  If `~foo` is `virtual`, this will quite happily work.  You lose the data being contiguous.  And you have to learn about `unique_ptr`, but you should learn about `unique_ptr` anyhow.

Second, you can create a `std::vector< boost::variant< foo, foo_subclass > >` or equivalent.  In this case, there ends up being enough storage for either a `foo` or a `foo_subclass`, and at the point of access the user has to determine if they are getting one or the other.  In theory, you could even write your own variant `variant` so that it knows that the types stored are related, and you could access either as a `foo`, and only the `foo_subclass` instances as their subclass.

The first is by far easier, the second is a far more advanced technique that probably is not worth your bother.

Comment: I see .. so I gather it's not possible, then, to switch it up and create a std::vector<foo_subclass> and put some foo's in it?

Comment: @Chap No.  Well, as always, it depends, does `foo_subclass` have a conversion constructor from `foo`?  `std::vector<T>` contains `T`s, and nothing else.

Comment: `foo` is a non-owning memory reference; `foo_subclass` comes with its own buffer for when we don't trust the memory's owner to protect it properly (in which case we make a copy of the memory).  Maybe subclassing is overkill or wrong, and I should just make everything look like `foo_subclass`, and only use its private buffer when necessary.  (So to answer your q, it would defeat the purpose to have a `foo`->`foo_subclass` conversion constructor)